# POSTGRESQL: How to add new column with data on existing table

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres and sql scripts so please bear with me :)
What I want to do is to add an existing column with data on an existing table.

Example of existing table:

```
NAME           AGE   
Adam           25
Tim            30
```

Now I want to add a new column ADDRESS with data for Adam and Tim.

I used the pgadmin interface for now to add directly to the table without script.

Comment: If the data is already in another table you can use `UPDATE ... FROM ...` to populate the new field from the other table, once you've added the column.

Comment: Does your table have any _unique key_ / _primary key_?,Show your actual table(_create script of the table_).From where your planing to add data to newly created column ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "TestTable"
(
  "ID" integer NOT NULL,
  "Name" character(255),
  "Age" integer,
  CONSTRAINT "TestTable_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)

Now I would like the script to add a new column "ADDRESS" and then there's already data for address.

Answer (score 6):

The command to add a column to a table is `alter table`:

```
alter table add column address varchar(255);
```

Or whatever your preferred data type is.  Personally, I think this is easier than pointing and clicking through an interface to add a column.

(Also note that the `column` keyword is strictly optional, and not even supported by all databases.)

Comment: The new column ADRESS will have the ff data:
Chicago
New York

What command should I use?

Comment: I am having the same problem. How to populate this new column with different information in each rows?

Comment: @shumanachowdhury . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not comments, with sample data, desired results, and code attempts.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE public.users
ADD COLUMN country_code text
```

// text datatype
// if you want to give size of datatype then use int(11)

Comment: There is no `int(11)` in Postgres (or standard SQL)