# How to add a new column to table without losing data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter

I have a table name emp with columns `id`, `name`, `salary`.
I want to add a new column name `isverified` of data type `boolean` with not null constraint and by default value false.

I already have a data in the tables, I don't want to lose this data. I want to make changes without losing data

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See documentation for [Alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertable.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POSTGRESQL: How to add new column with data on existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469937/postgresql-how-to-add-new-column-with-data-on-existing-table)

Comment: why do you think you will lose data?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE emp ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS isverified BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: SQL is a human readable language and OP's question was practically a sql statement by itself: 
> "add a new column name isverified of data type boolean with not null constraint and by default value false."